# How do I export a Telerik report to PDF - from inside an SSIS task?

Tags: c#, ssis, telerik, report

I need to export a Telerik report - to PDF - from within an SSIS task. I can export this report in a C# console application - using the following statement:

```
RenderingResult render = rptProc.RenderReport("PDF", instanceRptSource, null);
```

... but when I try and move the same code to an SSIS script task I get the following error:

> Could not find file 'Telerik.Reporting.resources'

I have put a reference to the Telerik.Reporting.dll in the script task, and I have tried putting that dll in the GAC, and loading it via the
`System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(execPath, fileName))`
method as well. None of these methods seem to fix the problem. As far as I can tell, there is no assembly, or dll, with the name Telerik.Reporting.resources.

Anyone have any ideas?